# Raise text without mathmode

Tags: math-mode

I want to be able to write text as 'raised to power' without mathmode. E.g. how can I write this without textmode?

```
$\text{Some text}^{change}$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Some text\textsuperscript{change}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use:

`Some text\textsuperscript{change}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Some text\textsuperscript{change}
\end{document}
```

[image: The result]